# Is this an appropriate to encode CSV attributes as parameters on the text/csv mime type?

Tags: rest, csv, mime-types

[RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) talks about the text/csv mime type, but doesn't go into some of the more obvious variations that one would have to support, for example the separator used (ok ok so if it's Csv then it should obviously be a comma) and whether there is a header row or not.

I'd like to add parameters like separator=, and headerrow=0|1 to the mime type such that REST APIs that consume CSV files can consume them appropriately.

The alternative would seem to be to add the parameters to the URL but that feels wrong.

Comment: Adding that kind of meta info to the ContentType feels also wrong to me … I would rather place them in custom `X-` headers, such as `X-CSV-Separator: ","`, `X-CSV-Header: "1"` …

Comment: But that makes them about the request, not the content, esp if it is in a multi part request.